# Passing String value from Unmanaged code to managed code?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, unmanaged, managed

hi i am returning a `LPTSTR` type of object from unmanaged code which essentially points to a string . i am in managed code now and i m unable to read it in C# . the string being returned is just "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"..

Here is my managed code snippet.

```
[DllImport("TableConfig.dll", EntryPoint = "?getTableConfigDlg@@QAEPA_WXZ", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        static extern String getColumnNamesFormat();
```

Is there anything wrong with this ???
How do i get meaningful data out of the string being returned from unmanaged code ?

Thanks

Native Code:-

```
for(int i=0; i<numCols; ++i)
{
    const bet_TableConfigColumn *col_p = tc_p->getColumn(i);
    const char* colName = tc_p->getKeyName(i);
    const char* colFormat = col_p->getFormat();
    str+=",";
    str+=colName;
    cout << "Col Name" << colName << "Format: " << colFormat;

} // end of for(i)
         LPTSTR pString=str.GetBuffer(0);
            str.ReleaseBuffer();
      return pString;
```

Comment: Try changing the return value in the managed extern to StringBuilder.  According to the DllImport documentation, StringBuilder should be used for [out] parameters or return values.

Comment: Also, be sure to check the definition of your LPTSTR.  If UNICODE is defined for your unmanaged build, it will actually be wchar_t*, in which case you want Unicode rather than Ansi for the CharSet.

Comment: Nope the value seems to be gone when the control returns out ofunmanaged function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed:

```
DllImport("TableConfig.dll", EntryPoint = "?getTableConfigDlg@@QAEPA_WXZ")]
static extern void getColumnNamesFormat( StringBuilder tableNames );

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder( 255 );
getColumnNamesFormat( result );
```

Native:

change method signature to return void, take in a LPTSTR for the managed buffer.

```
_tcscpy(managedBuffer, str);
```

Comment: If that was the problem, he'd get back a single character.

Comment: @Blindy good point. Anything wrong with the proposed solution?

Comment: Nope i am still getting junk ,, all rectangular boxes.... :( :( :( .i tried uni,ansi none of it works...

Comment: Just posted above... plz take a look

Comment: @Geek return str.GetBuffer(0); and use Marshal.PtrToStringUni() to read the string.

Comment: Naah , doesnt work either... I just observed this while debuggin , as long as the control is in the dll scope the value is absolutely right but when the control goes beyond the return step the value of str.GetBuffer(0) changes to junk .... i am wondering if the memory assosciated with that variable is being freed ????

Comment: @Geek did you remove the "LPTSTR pString=str.GetBuffer(0) str.ReleaseBuffer();" from your code? That pString isn't needed. Also, after you Marshal the string from a managed context you'll need to call "Marshal.FreeHGlobal()" on the original pointer returned.

Comment: You're still way off Brandon, this has nothing to do with how the string is represented in memory, *the string gets deallocated when the function ends*.

Comment: exactly the string is being deallocated when the method finishes the execution...

Answer (score -1):

A shot in the dark here, but is your native function returning an object allocated on the stack? If so, you can't do that.

Once you're done fixing that problem, you can start thinking of how you're going to dispose of the memory after it's no longer of any use, or you'll have a memory leak on your hands.

Comment: Okie , i am free to change the design, what is the best practice for these kinda issues where a string needs to be passed to and fro across managed , unmanaged???

Comment: Show the native code, specifically dealing with allocating and passing the character array.

Comment: <pre>for(int i=0; i<numCols; ++i)
 {
  const bet_TableConfigColumn *col_p = tc_p->getColumn(i);
  const char* colName = tc_p->getKeyName(i);
  const char* colFormat = col_p->getFormat();
  
  str+=",";
  str+=colName;

  
  cout << "Col Name" << colName << "Format: " << colFormat;
  
 } // end of for(i)
 


LPTSTR pString=str.GetBuffer(0);
str.ReleaseBuffer();


 return pString;
<code>

Comment: There's your problem, you're releasing the buffer *before* returning it, so only garbage reaches the other side.

Comment: @blindy: i dont think thats the issue . i removed the line and it didnt work either.. i am still getting the same junk values...

Comment: I'm not sure what line you think you removed, but that's the same code as before. Besides `str` is *allocated on the stack*, just like I said in my answer. You have to move your buffer on the heap if you want it to remain alive after the function is over.

Comment: How exactly do i keep my string on the heap ? Can you please help me out with this ?

Comment: Well the typical way is to pass a pre-allocated buffer from the caller side (C#) and fill it in with `strcpy` from your function. An alternative is to allocate memory inside your function (`new char[str.Length()` or whatever), fill it in (`strcpy`) and return it, but then your caller has to somehow deallocate that memory. That being said, I wonder what the point of getting a buffer and immediately releasing it is.

Comment: If I remember when I get home, sure!